# SSH access to AWS Ubuntu EC2 Instance times out

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I'm new to AWS, I've setup a micro instance on Ubuntu.

I have created and downloaded a key pair.

I have also set up the security user group, everything has SSH set to all on port 22.

I keep getting *timeouts* on the SSH login, I have done the following:

```
chmod key-name.pem

ssh -i key-name.pem ubuntu@public-DNS
```

Not sure what else I can do to get into the server.

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually mean port 20, or 22?  22 is default for SSH.

Comment: yes, I mean port 22.

Comment: Showing some debug info using `-v` or even `-vvv` will help. Also, what does `chmod` without permissions do?

Comment: Hey Arjan I'm not familar with unix commands, can you specify how I can use these commands? regarding chmod, I have tried both with and without it.

Answer (score 1):

Log-in to [Amazon Web Services](https://console.aws.amazon.com/) and check the followings:

- *Security Group* for your instance is **allowing *Inbound* SSH access** (check: *view rules*).
- For VPC instance, **check its attached *Route table*** which should have `0.0.0.0/0` as Destination and your *Internet Gateway* as Target.
- Double check your route info in *System Log* in *Networking* of the instance.

For more details, check: [Troubleshooting Connecting to Your Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to SSH your instance over internet then create an Elastic IP(public ip) and then associate it to your instance and use it to SSH into your machine.

Using private IP for SSH works good only when the machine from which you are initiating an SSH connection has access to your instance locally.